# Add text to cart page when using the "woocommerce_cart_contents_changed" hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the "woocommerce_cart_contents_changed" hook to check if a user has already added a specific product to basket however, would also like to display some text on the page to inform them that the product has been removed. The function takes 1 argument which returns an array of all cart items. If anyone could help, that would be great. Thank you.

I have tried to just simply echo content within the function. I would like some text to be displayed anywhere on the cart page once the product is added to the basket.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for displaying cart items after the user add some item to the cart you need to use the AJAX function which updates the HTML page dynamically.
But if you just want to display what is in the cart after the page reload you can try that code:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce Cart Items
 * Description: Display all items in WooCommerce cart with shortcode.
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Text Domain: wc-cart-items
 */

class WC_Cart_Items_Shortcode {

  public static function init() {
    add_shortcode( 'wc_cart_items', array( __CLASS__, 'shortcode' ) );
  }

  public static function shortcode() {
    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    $items = '';

    foreach ( $cart as $cart_item ) {
      $product = $cart_item['data'];
      $items .= sprintf( '<li>%s - %s x %s</li>', $product->get_name(), $cart_item['quantity'], $product->get_price() );
    }

    return sprintf( '<ul>%s</ul>', $items );
  }
}

add_action( 'init', array( 'WC_Cart_Items_Shortcode', 'init' ) );
```